# Really slow mouse speed in CentOS9 Stream

Tags: centos, mouse, xinput

I am a new Linux user and I have tried to increase my mouse speed as the sensitivity has changed recently and it is very slow to move.

I have looked online and tried to change the sensitivity using xinput, however it shows:

> WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server

Is there a way to stop using xinput against this Xwayland server?

[image: Terminal error message]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/mouse-sensitivity.html.en